# Show hidden div on li has class 'selected'

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

i have a script that display a div that is hidden in a li, but currently it only show the div from the first li, the script add the class 'selected' on the other li but show the div from the first one.

Here is my code

```
$(document).on("pageinit", function(e){
    $(".menu_slide").click(function(event) {
        $(this).parents('li').addClass('selected');

        var sm = $($("#"+ $(e.target).attr('id') +" :jqmData(slidemenu)").data('slidemenu'));   
        var sa =  $('li.selected').attr('class');
        // console.log(sm);
        if($("li").hasClass("selected")){
            $(document).on("click", ":jqmData(slidemenu)", function(e) {
                // console.log(sm.data('slideopen'));
                slidemenu(sm, sm.data('slideopen'));
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
            }); sta
        } else {
            // Todo code
        }
    });
});

function slidemenu(sm, only_close) {
    if (!sm.data('slideopen') && !only_close) {

        var swipe = $('.menu_slide_swipe');
        var wi = $(window).width();

        // Portrait Phone
        if(wi == 320){
            sm.show().animate({ left:'31px', avoidTransforms: true, useTranslate3d: true}, 'fast'); 
            swipe.show().animate({ left:'6px', avoidTransforms: true, useTranslate3d: true}, 'fast');
            sm.data('slideopen', true);
        }

        // Landscape Phone
        if (wi == 569){
            sm.show().animate({ left:'307px', avoidTransforms: true, useTranslate3d: true}, 'fast');
            swipe.show().animate({ left:'281px', avoidTransforms: true, useTranslate3d: true}, 'fast');
            sm.data('slideopen', true);         
        } 

        // Portrait Tablet
        if(wi == 769){
            sm.show().animate({width:'450px', left:'302px', avoidTransforms: true, useTranslate3d: true}, 'fast');  
            swipe.show().animate({ left:'276px', avoidTransforms: true, useTranslate3d: true}, 'fast');
            sm.data('slideopen', true);
        }

        // Landscape Tablet
        if(wi == 1024){
            sm.show().animate({width:'450px', left:'552px', avoidTransforms: true, useTranslate3d: true}, 'fast');  
            swipe.show().animate({ left:'525px', avoidTransforms: true, useTranslate3d: true}, 'fast');
            sm.data('slideopen', true);
        }

        if ($(":jqmData(role='header')").data('position') == 'fixed') {
        } else {
            $(":jqmData(slidemenu)").css('margin-left', '10px');
        }

    } else {
        var swipe = $('.menu_slide_swipe');
        sm.animate({left:'-260px', avoidTransforms: false, useTranslate3d: true}, 'fast', function(){sm.hide()});
        swipe.animate({left:'-60px', avoidTransforms: false, useTranslate3d: true}, 'fast', function(){swipe.hide()});
        sm.data('slideopen', false);
        $(":jqmData(slidemenu)").css('margin-left', '0px');
        $("li.ui-li").removeClass("selected");
    }
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT**

```
$(".menu_slide").click(function (event) {
    $(this).parents('li').addClass('selected');
    var sm = $($("#" + $(e.target).attr('id') + " :jqmData(slidemenu)").data('slidemenu'));
    var sa = $('li.selected').attr('class');
});
$(document).on("click", "li.selected :jqmData(slidemenu)", function (e) {
    var sm = $($("#" + $(e.target).attr('id') + " :jqmData(slidemenu)").data('slidemenu'));
    slidemenu(sm, sm.data('slideopen'));
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause or not, but a click event inside a click event is usually a bad idea, especially one that's delegated off the `document`.

Comment: you can create a jsfindle with html and js? maybe I can help you

Comment: I don't see the part where you *show* that div

Comment: Frederik.L - I'm assuming `slidemenu(sm, sm.data('slideopen'));` is what shows the div.

Comment: i just made an update with all the code in the js file.

Answer (score 1):

Move the binding of the event  to outside of `$(".menu_slide").click` event. This makes the event to be bound multiple times to the same element

```
 $(document).on("click", "li.selected :jqmData(slidemenu)", function(e) {
      // console.log(sm.data('slideopen'));
      slidemenu(sm, sm.data('slideopen'));
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `$(".menu_slide").click(function(event) {
  $(this).parents('li').addClass('selected');
  var sm = $($("#"+ $(e.target).attr('id') +" :jqmData(slidemenu)").data('slidemenu')); 
  var sa =  $('li.selected').attr('class');
 });
 $(document).on("click", "li.selected :jqmData(slidemenu)", function(e) {
  var sm = $($("#"+ $(e.target).attr('id') +" :jqmData(slidemenu)").data('slidemenu')); 
  slidemenu(sm, sm.data('slideopen'));
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
 });`

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to ever be removing the 'selected' class from any <li>s. On each click, before adding this line:

```
$(this).parents('li').addClass('selected');
```

Remove 'selected' class from all potentially affected LIs and reset it.

Also, as Kevin B mentioned, a click within a click is seriously weird structure. You'd likely be better off just having the click even on `jqmData(slidemenu)` at the outset then checking for the 'selected' class within it, instead of trying to place the if outside and conditionally bind it. Or, depending on the HTML, perhaps do something like `li.selected > :jqmData(slidemenu)' as your selector (I'm guessing at how your DOM is structured, obviously).

Comment: if you see de code edited above it removes de 'selected' class on div return to 'hidde', what i hace to do now is to check if the div to show is child of the 'li.selected'.